# Loading javascripts at the bottom using Requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I've been trying to implement this [POST](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs). But i have seen that using RequireJs either in head or in the bottom, it always loads the dependent javascript files in the head. Is there any way i can force RequireJs to always load the dependent scripts at the bottom??

The problem i am trying to solve is: I want to load specific controller depending on the route. But i have been defining ng-controller="MyCtrl" attribute in the views. So when the all the dependent scripts and specific controller loads its not able to find the ng-controller attribute and gives me the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Is this the issue or am i missing something else here?

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js You can also combine all scripts into one without the dependency to Modulerr.js

Answer (score 0):

Most asynchronous loaders would load the scripts in head. There is practically no advantage in trying to load anything in the bottom at this point now that the DOM has already been parsed. So whether you add require.js in the head or bottom it should not matter.

About the error you are getting:-

Are you using something like
resolve: resolveController('/app/controllers/customersController.js')
and included routeResolver.js

Comment: Yes i have followed exactly the way blog has written. Its working the only problem is once my controller loads at the head its not able to find the ng-controller attribute of my view which is still loading i suppose.

Comment: @VishwaKumar It does not matter if the script loads in head or by the </body>. All browsers need is having parsed Javascript objects which are then referenced elsewhere. In the case of AngularJS all we need is that the code for defining a service/controller being executed BEFORE the DOM is compiled. So I really doubt your haunch that this is because of script at the bottom. I recommend you for a moment to think that the problem is something else. Is it possible that you can create a plnkr.

Comment: @VishvaKumar Look down in the comments section of http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs you will notice one comment where people are complaining about there template is loaded before the JS just like I said. SO you are not the only one who had the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load the script in header you could "require" the "require" function and then require the module whatever you want to use:

```
define(['require'], function(require){

    ...

    var ctrl = require('path/to/your/controller');

});
```

Comment: how does this make require to load scripts at bottom ? Could you please explain more or give some pointers to check out? Thanks!